# Removing users with UID > 1000

Tags: shell-script, users

How do I write a shell script that deletes all local user accounts
with UID > 1000 on a Linux system?

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for userid in `/etc/passwd`
do
if ((“userid” >= 1000)); then
userdel -r $user
done
```

How do I set the criteria to delete all accounts with UID > 1000? 
This is the part I have not been able to search for. 
I am not even sure what I have done so far is correct,
but I read it on some other post which has a similar question
but it is slightly different.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?  How did the results differ from expectations or intent?

Comment: What happened when you ran that code? Please add the results

Comment: You might also want to pop your code into https://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Oh dear...  I don't think I am even close when I popped the script into shellcheck.net.  Thank you for the neat app !

Comment: Do you also want to remove the essential user `nobody`, or should there be an exception made for that?

Comment: Hmmmm good question, I would leave that.

Comment: If you have any good and easy tutorial, I would really appreciate it.  I am trying to learn this !

Comment: (1) When somebody asks you “What have you tried?”, they don’t want to be told that you searched the Internet. We *expect* you to do research; please stop putting “I have been searching the Internet …” back into your question. (2) We also expect you to *try* to solve your problem. It’s misleading to say something like «testing the UID is the part where I’m stuck» when, in fact, the code you have is soooooo very far from being correct. (3) You should say where you got that code (i.e., link to it). (4) In English, you can say “a script that deletes” or “a script to delete”, but not “… that to …”.

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) In your text (and the title) you say “>”, but in your code you say ```>=```. Please be consistent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/543479/newbiewithlinux and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/543481/newbie2022.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question without having it reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Should rather be something like:

```
getent passwd |
  awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 {print $1}' |
  xargs -n1 -rd '\n' echo userdel -r --
```

(remove the `echo` if that looks right). That assumes the GNU implementation of `xargs`, but that's the one generally used in non-embedded Linux-based systems (the ones you would do user management on).

`getent passwd` dumps the passwd user database, whether it's stored in `/etc/passwd`, postgresql, sqlite3, LDAP...

In that database dump the entries are colon-separated with the first field the username and the third the user id.

`awk` is the obvious choice to process this kind of data.

We invoke it with `-F:` (short for `-v FS=:`) to set the field separator to `:`, and for each record, if the third field is a number greater or equal to 1000, we print the first.

`xargs` takes that output, considered `n`ewline `d`elimited and for each `1` entry, calls `echo`, with `userdel`, `-r`, `--` and that entry as arguments.

Replace `getent passwd |` with `</etc/passwd` if you only want to consider the username in `/etc/passwd`.

As @Kusalananda said, there may be some system accounts such as `nobody` that you would not want to remove.

For instance, on my system, I find:

```
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:108:Libvirt Qemu,,,:/var/lib/libvirt:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

So you may want to add some more criteria to your selection such as `$3 >= 1000 && $3 < 60000` or `$3 >= 1000 && $6 ~ "^/home/"` (home directory under `/home`) or `$7 !~ "nologin"` (shell doesn't contain nologin), or membership to some group, or has a valid password...

Beware that `userdel`'s stdin will be /dev/null, so it won't be able to prompt anything from you. To avoid that, you can reword it as:

```
xargs -n1 -rd '\n' -a <(
    getent passwd |
      awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 {print $1}'
  ) echo userdel -r --
```

Where this time `xargs` takes its input from the file passed after `-a` instead of stdin and leaves `userdel`'s stdin alone.

The filename in that case is a result of ksh-style process substitution (also supported by bash), where `<(...)` is expanded to the path of a pipe with the end being fed by the output of `getent | awk`.

Comment: In this _particular_ case, parsing `/etc/passwd` is probably safer, as the user wants to remove only local accounts.

Comment: @Kusalananda, local accounts could be stored some other way than in `/etc/passwd` though. But yes I agree it's more likely to have them stored in LDAP remotely where userdel would likely not work and not be desirable than them being stored locally in some sqlite or SQL DB instead of /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` command will output the usernames of all local users with UID greater than or equal to 1000, and will skip any user whose name is `nobody` (this is a user that you most likely *don't* want to remove):

```bash
awk -F : '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" { print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

It parses the `/etc/passwd` file as a set of line-based records with `:`-delimited fields.  It tests the 3rd field for values greater than or equal to 1000, it ensures that the 1st field is not `nobody`, and then prints the first field.  You may want to change the second test from `$1 != "nobody"` to something like `$3 < 10000` to avoid hitting any special accounts with high UIDs.

You may then use a loop to read the names and delete them, one at a time (see [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/719371/116858) for how to use `xargs` to do this instead):

```bash
awk -F : '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" { print $1 }' /etc/passwd |
while IFS= read -r name; do
    userdel -r "$name"
done
```